# How to format time and date at axes of figure

Tags: python, datetime, plot, formatting, axis

I am working on a figure that should simply plot time on y-axis and date on x-axis.
My input is a date string, which I already convert into a date by help of timedate.

I also manage to get the figure, but struggle with formatting the axis. I found examples to tick labels for matplotlib.dates, but not for my objects of type datetime. Aim would be to have ticks at every 3 hours on y-axis (0, 3, 6, 9....24) and ticks for each full year and each month on x-axis.

Input is a list with objects of type "snapshot" with dates of type string in the attribute snapshot.date, that include date and time (eg. '21.02.2021 08:47'). Strings are formated to datetime. When they are separted to date and time with strftime they are unfortunately converted to string. So I convert them back to date/time with strptime. Is there a better way to keep the date format and separate time and date?

The code looks like this

```
    fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.5, 5))  # Create a figure and an axes.
    datetime_object_list = [datetime.strptime(snapshot.date, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M') for snapshot in snapshots if snapshot.stcd == stcd_ID]

    date_string_list = [datetime.strftime(datetime_object, '%d %m %y') for datetime_object in datetime_object_list]
    date_object_list = [datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d %m %y').date() for date_string in date_string_list]

    time_string_list = [datetime.strftime(datetime_object, '%H:%M') for datetime_object in datetime_object_list]
    time_object_list = [datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M').time() for time_string in time_string_list]

    # plot sensors
    ax1.plot_date(date_object_list, time_object_list, xdate=True, ydate=True, marker='o', color='C1')

    # define limits of axes
    y_min = datetime.strptime('00:00', '%H:%M').time()
    y_max = datetime.strptime('23:59', '%H:%M').time()
    ax1.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
```

So far the output looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzSMN.png)

Would be very nice, if someone has an idea!
Thanks a lot and BR
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with xticks and yticks and also prepared a better example code that runs as a stand alone:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

dt1 = datetime(2011, 11, 1, 23, 2)
dt2 = datetime(2011, 10, 1, 23, 2)
dt3 = datetime(2011, 8, 12, 3, 2)
dt4 = datetime(2011, 8, 14, 23, 2)
dt5 = datetime(2011, 9, 12, 2, 2)
dt6 = datetime(2010, 10, 5, 13, 2)
dt7 = datetime(2010, 11, 4, 12, 2)
dt8 = datetime(2010, 5, 12, 3, 2)
dt9 = datetime(2010, 2, 14, 8, 2)

dt_list = [dt1 ,dt2, dt3, dt4, dt5, dt6, dt7, dt8, dt9]

year_list = [dt.year for dt in dt_list]
year_set = list(set(year_list))  # liste statt set, damit unten index funktioniert!

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# create scatter plots for each year with different color
for year in year_set:
    dt_list_year = [dt for dt in dt_list if dt.year == year]
    t__list = [dt.time() for dt in dt_list_year]
    d__list = [datetime.strptime(str(dt.month) + ' ' + str(dt.day), '%m %d').date() for dt in dt_list_year]  # month and day without year -> referece to year 1900 automatically
    ax1.plot_date(d__list, t__list, xdate=True, ydate=True, color="C" + str(year_set.index(year)), label=str(year))

# formatting x
month = list(range(1, 13))
x_ticks_ = [datetime.strptime(str(month_i), '%m').date() for month_i in month]
x_labels = [x_ticksi.strftime('%b') for x_ticksi in x_ticks_]  # '%b' -> Jan, Feb, Mar etc.
plt.xticks(x_ticks_, x_labels)

# formatting y
hours = list(range(0, 24, 2))
y_ticks_ = [datetime.strptime(str(hours_i), '%H').time() for hours_i in hours]
plt.yticks(y_ticks_)

ax1.set_xlabel('month')
ax1.legend(loc='best')
```

Following figure is generated:
[image: figure with times vs date, nicely formatted]